# how can i fix this issue with tensorflow_probability?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I import TensorFlow probability regularly and these are my two layers:

`tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(10),`

However, I keep receiving this message when I run this:

File "dark.py", line 10, in 

`import tensorflow_probability as tfp
File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
from tensorflow_probability.python import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from tensorflow_probability.python import bijectors
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from tensorflow_probability.python.bijectors.absolute_value import AbsoluteValue
File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\absolute_value.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.bijectors import bijector
File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\bijector.py", line 213, in <module>
    class Bijector(tf.Module):
File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\bijector.py", line 570, in Bijector
    _TF_MODULE_IGNORED_PROPERTIES = tf.Module._TF_MODULE_IGNORED_PROPERTIES.union(
AttributeError: type object 'Module' has no attribute '_TF_MODULE_IGNORED_PROPERTIES'`

Is there any way to solve this problem? I have searhed on the internet, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: is it possible to write a bayes_prob in another way?

Comment: i have this so far:

Comment: def bayes_prob(layer):
        with tf.compact.v1.name_scope("bayesian_prob", values=[layer]):
            model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(10),
            ])

        logits = model(features)
        neg_log_likelihood = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                labels=labels, logits=logits)
        kl = sum(model.losses)
        loss = neg_log_likelihood + kl
        train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
        return model

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23544#issuecomment-436337914) I think it's compatibility issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind (this is my other account), if you have the same problem then type

```
pip list
```

and check if you have tf.nightly, if you do then you need to type in this command

```
pip install tf.nightly-2.0-preview
```

It should work.

Comment: Actually `tf-nightly-2.0-preview` stopped updating recently (most recent on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly-2.0-preview/#history) is from Oct 2), with the official 2.0 stable release. You should now use `tf-nightly` which now updates on the 2.x line.